# Algorithm to generate (not quite) spanning set in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

This follows on from this question:

[Algorithm to generate spanning set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460479/algorithm-to-generate-spanning-set)

Given this input: [1,2,3,4]

I'd like to generate this set of sets in python:

```
[1] [2] [3] [4]
[1] [2] [3,4]
[1] [2, 3, 4]
[1] [2,3] [4]
[1,2] [3] [4]
[1,2] [3,4]
[1,2,3] [4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

So unlike the previous question, the order of the list is retained.

Ideally the code would work for n items in the list

Thanks very much

EDIT 2: Could anyone advise me on how to do this if the original input is a string rather than a list (where each word in the string becomes an item in a list). Thanks!

EDIT: added [1] [2, 3, 4] Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Did you forgot the set [1] [2,3,4] ?

Comment: Why is there no `[1], [2, 3, 4]` in the output?

Comment: What you're trying to do was something like the part 1 of the question [Python: show all possible groupings of a list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9088321/1132524).

Comment: It is somewhat like that. Although I'd hope to generalise to splitting the list into 'up to n' parts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also enjoy a recursive solution:

```
def span(lst):
  yield [lst]
  for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    for x in span(lst[i:]):
      yield [lst[:i]] + x
```

#### Explanation

We exploit recursion here to break the problem down. The approach is the following:

For every list, the whole list is a valid spanning: `[1,2,3,4] => [[1,2,3,4]]`.

For every list that is longer than size `1`, we can use the first item as a group and then apply the same algorithm on the remaining list to get all the combined results:

```
[1,2,3] => 
  [[1]] + [[2], [3]]  # => [[1], [2], [3]]
  [[1]] + [[2,3]]     # => [[1], [2,3]]
```

For every list that is longer than size `2`, we can just as well use the first **two** items as a group and then apply the same algorithm on the remaining list and combine the results:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] =>
  [[1,2]] + [[3], [4], [5]]  # => [[1,2], [3], [4], [5]]
  [[1,2]] + [[3,4], [5]]     # => [[1,2], [3,4], [5]]
  [[1,2]] + [[3], [4,5]]     # => [[1,2], [3], [4,5]]
  [[1,2]] + [[3,4,5]]        # => [[1,2], [3,4,5]]
```

We can see that the possible combinations on the right side are indeed all possible groupings of the remainder of the list, `[3,4,5]`.

For every list that is longer than ... etc. Thus, the final algorithm is the following:

1. yield the whole list (it is always a valid spanning, see above)
2. For every possible splitting of the list, yield the left-hand part of the list combined with all possible spannings of the right-hand part of the list.

`yield` is a special keyword in Python that make the function a *generator*, which means that it returns a iterable object that can be used to enumerate all results found. You can transform the result into a list using the `list` constructor function: `list(span([1,2,3,4]))`.

Comment: Can I just take a couple of hours to work through them, then I will do so :)

Comment: @user: Fair enough :) Have fun!

Comment: Would you be able to explain a little how this works to a novice - just a couple of lines in prose? Don't worry though if you don't have time

Comment: @user1195889: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Adjusting one of the solution from [Python: show all possible groupings of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9088321/1132524):

```
from itertools import combinations

def cut(lst, indexes):
    last = 0
    for i in indexes:
        yield lst[last:i]
        last = i
    yield lst[last:]

def generate(lst, n):
    for indexes in combinations(list(range(1,len(lst))), n - 1):
        yield list(cut(lst, indexes))

data = [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(1, len(data)+1):  # the only difference is here
    for g in generate(data, i):
        print(g)

"""
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
n = len(a)
for num_splits in range(n):
    for splits in itertools.combinations(range(1, n), num_splits):
        splices = zip([0] + list(splits), list(splits) + [n])
        print([a[i:j] for i, j in splices])
```

prints

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
[[1], [2, 3, 4]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3, 4]]
[[1], [2, 3], [4]]
[[1, 2], [3], [4]]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```